# SAS, if statement within plot statement

Tags: if-statement, sas

I want to add the if statement to my plot to change titles in different scenarios. 
I know my code in the first sgplot won't work. Do we have something similar to this?

```
%let group = A B C;

/*something I want but didn't work*/
proc sgplot data=input_data ;
series x=num_accounts y=income;
if  length(&group.)=2 then 
title "VAR1=5 and VAR2=4";
else if length(&group.)=1 then
title "VAR1=5";
run;

/*plot without if statement */
proc sgplot data=input_data ;
series x=num_accounts y=income;
title "VAR1=5";
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're just checking the length of a macro variable, yes, it's possible - in a macro `%if`.  But you have to have a macro wrapper at least.

```
%macro plot_me(group=);

%if %length(&group.)=2 %then %do;
title "VAR1=5 and VAR2=4";
%end;
%else %if %length(&group.)=1 %then %do;
title "VAR1=5";
%end;
proc sgplot data=sashelp.class ;
series x=age y=height;
run;
%mend plot_me;

%let group=A B C;
%plot_me(group=&group.);
```

Other options you have in ODS Graphics/SGPLOT include attribute maps and annotation, both of which are datastep driven and thus could potentially be used for more complicated conditions.

You could also use the graph template language (GTL) which gives you some more options, I think, if you're going into more complicated things.  That does allow you to write "if" statements of a sort.

Macro language is the right place for the specific example you presented, but GTL or attribute maps may be better for a realistic example depending on what you're doing.

Comment: I ran your code there is no title come out. I tried it on my real data, no title neither.

Comment: @user1481397 The title won't come out if you don't have SGPLOT set up to use titles (usually with GTITLE option on the ODS statement).  It won't come out in your code either.  That's not related to the question, though.